# How to specify additionalProperties with l5-swagger

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi

I am trying to write OpenAPI documentation for a project (written with Laravel) and struggling with several API points.

One returns

```
{
    "active_options": {
        "1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "type": "type1"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "type": "type2"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "name3",
            "type": "type3"
        }
    },
    "server": {
        "url": "URL...",
        "settings1": "value"
    },
    "message": "Server settings retrieved."
}
```

I am struggling with how to write this annotation with l5-swagger plugin.
The "1", "2", "3" are optional and any combination of them is valid.

I wanted to use `optionalProperties`, but I don't know how to combine them together.

This is the closest I got:

```
     *   @OA\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Settings",
     *     @OA\JsonContent(
     *       @OA\Property(property="options",
     *         @OA\Items(
     *            @OA\Property(property="name", type="string"),
     *            @OA\Property(property="type", type="string")
     *         )
     *       ),
     *     )
     *   ),
```

But the sample generates this:

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which obviously is missing the `"1":` ... part.
Maybe a better question would be how to do unnamed properties?

Comment: I have the same problem. The docs are not very complete

Comment: @guergana see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
    /**
     *
     * @OA\Schema(
     *     schema="ExampleResponse",
     *   @OA\Xml(name="ExampleResponse"),
     *   @OA\Property(property="message", type="string", example="My solution."),
     *   @OA\Property(property="errors", type="object",
     *     @OA\AdditionalProperties(type="array",
     *       @OA\Items(
     *          @OA\Property(property="name", type="string"),
     *          @OA\Property(property="type", type="string")
     *       )
     *     )
     *   ),
     * )

     *
     */
```